# can't figure how to resolve to a variable

Tags: java

i have this code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lectureArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int [] arr = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--);
        System.out.println(arr[i] ) ;
    }

}
```

and i have this error: "i cannot be resolved to a variable" . 
no matter how much i tried to get rid of it, it just making more errors or not resolving the error in the first place

Comment: Remove the last semi-colon on `for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--);`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786982/2557685) explains the the difference of loops with and without braces.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon from your for loop. Change

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--);
```

to

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon from last from second last line of your code as below

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--);    <---- This is causing you problem
        System.out.println(arr[i] ) ;
```

to

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(arr[i] ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems are very common when you don't follow coding standards. Make sure to format your code properly. Using `for`, `while`, `if` etc. without braces ( {} ) leads to these type of barely noticeable errors.

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--); // **;** ends the scope of your loop
        System.out.println(arr[i] ) ; // so **i** is not visible here.
```

This is the correct format.

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
        System.out.println(arr[i] ) ;
}
```

Don't hesitate since it take one additional line. but it will save a lot of time when debugging and even reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think by removing semicolon(;) from the second last line of the code will be enough to get rid of this problem.