# Why does this for loop over an ArrayList generate a warning that "the for statement does not loop" in IntelliJ

Tags: java, for-loop, intellij-idea, break

I have an `ArrayList` that contains instances of the `Staff` class. When I write the following code I am told by IntelliJ that the '`for` statement does not loop':

```
public String getTypist() {
    String tempTy = "";
    for (Staff g : staffList) {
        if (g.getStaffID().contains("TY") && g.isAvailable()){
            tempTy = g.getStaffID();
        }
        staffList.remove(g);
        staffWorking.add(g);
        break;
    }

    return tempTy;
}
```

I'm really confused as I thought that this was the way to properly use a `for` loop on an `ArrayList`. What am I doing incorrectly with my `for` loop?

Comment: You call `break;` during the first iteration, so the loop will never iterate. Also, you can't modify an `ArrayList` while you're iterating it.

Comment: why did you put break if you want to loop over the List ?

Comment: Just remove the break statement.

Comment: Go to your IDE, start this in debugging and set a breakpoint at the start of the method. Then step it through. You will immediately see your error. You'll also have to use an Iterator to remove elements while iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop contains a `break` statement which always executes no matter what happens before in the loop, so after the very first looping occurs, the `break` happens, and nothing else is looped afterwards. This basically makes it as though there was no `for` loop at all, as executing code one time is the default way a series of statements are executed. Correcting this involves making sure the `break` executes only some of the loops (specifically, making sure it only executes on the loop you want to be the last loop). Making that correction with the addition of some other fixes you would get code similar to this:

```
public String getTypist() {
    for (Staff s : staffList) {
        if (s.getStaffID().contains("TY") && s.isAvailable()){
            staffList.remove(s);
            staffWorking.add(s);
            return s.getStaffID();
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

However, there is an alternative solution that would allow you to avoid iterating over the `ArrayList` at all. You can replace that code with this code and it will work without any `for` loop because it uses the methods of the `ArrayList` itself to accomplish the task:

```
public String getTypist() {
    ArrayList<Staff> staffWorking = new ArrayList<>(staffList);        
    staffWorking.removeIf(staff -> !(staff.isAvailable() && staff.getStaffID().contains("TY")));

    staffList.removeAll(staffWorking);

    Optional<Staff> typist = staffWorking.stream().findFirst();
    if(typist.isPresent()){
        return typist.getStaffID();
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Though even that could be simplified and improved to this (*this code supports concurrent filtering so on multi-processor systems it will be much faster*):

```
private static final Predicate<Staff> isATypistWorker = 
    staff -> staff.isAvailable() && staff.getStaffID().contains("TY");

public String getTypist() {
    ArrayList<Staff> typistWorkers = staffList.stream()
         .parallel()
         .filter(isATypistWorker)
         .distinct()
         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    staffList.removeAll(typistWorkers);
    staffWorkers.addAll(typistWorkers);

    Optional<Staff> typist = typistWorkers.stream().findFirst();

    return typist.isPresent() ? typist.getStaffID() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't looping because you always `break` after the first iteration of the loop. I think you need braces around your `if` statement.

```
public String getTypist() {
    String tempTy = "";

    for (Staff g : staffList) {
        if (g.getStaffID().contains("TY") && g.isAvailable()) {
            tempTy = g.getStaffID();
            staffList.remove(g);
            staffWorking.add(g);
            break;
        }
    }

    return tempTy;
}
```

Also the code I posted won't work because you can't remove from an `ArrayList` while looping through it. But that is a different issue.

Comment: I used the break as i was trying to find the first instance that met the criteria and then stop...i guess a for loop is not the correct statement?

Comment: The difference between the code I posted and the code you posted is I have brackets after my `if` statement to contain the rest of the logic in the loop. If you don't understand the difference, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786982/2464657). Also a `for` loop won't work for you because you cannot remove from an `ArrayList` while iterating over it. If you don't understand that, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431981/remove-elements-from-collection-while-iterating).